# How to find the maximum element and its index in the matrix using the max function?

Tags: matlab

The program does not correctly count the maximum

```
clc   
A = [   13 54 21 ;
        16 69 13 ; 
        22 23 32];

[r,c,v] = find(A == max(A(:)));

disp(['max ',num2str(v)])
disp(['index ',num2str([r,c])])
```

The program does not correctly count the maximum, but the indices are correct

max 1 - false,  must be 69 ||
index 2  2 - true

Comment: What's wrong with `[m,idx] = max(A)`?

Comment: Why did you think the function `find` would return the max value `69`. The documentation states: "`[row,col,v] = find(___)` also returns vector `v`, which contains **the nonzero elements of X**". In your example, `X=A == max(A(:))`, which means `X` is a matrix of _logical indices_, which only have values `0` or `1`.

Comment: Then how to get the number 69? If it outputs after 0 or 1?

Comment: What results do you want if there are more than one maximizing entries? Say `A = [13 54 21; 16 69 13; 22 23 69];`

Comment: `disp(['max ', num2str(A(r,c))])`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
%For r2018b and later
[val,idx] = max(A,[],'all');
%For earlier versions
[val,idx] = max(A(:));
```

Maximum element value is val, val == A(idx). For given syntax, val and idx are guaranteed to be numbers, not vectors or matrices.
If you want row and column subscripts, use ind2sub function

```
[r,c] = ind2sub(size(A), idx);
```

Comment: `[val,idx] = max(A,[],'all')` doesn't seem to work in R2018b. Only the single-output version works

Comment: Could you please check [val,idx] = max(A,[],'all','linear') or [val,idx] = max(A,[],[1 2],'linear') ? I'm using r2017b and wrote the answer using max function online reference

Comment: The online reference always follows the latest release, and unfortunately doesn’t state when options were added to a function. The `'all'` option is a very recent addition.